# On the conditions on a basic property of integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, graphing-functions

In all the places I've seen this property described;

$$\left|{\int_{{\,a}}^{{\,b}}{{f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}}} \right| \le \int_{{\,a}}^{{\,b}}{{\left| {f\left( x \right)} \right|\,\mathrm{d}x}}$$

The condition that $a \leq x \leq b$ is never specified. I assume there must be such a condition, because considering, say, $y=x^2$ from $x=2$ to $x=1$,(so that $a$ is greater than $b$) the absolute values don't impact the result, and obviously the expression on the right of the inequation is negative, while the other isn't.

Comment: Integration is almost always done for some a and b such that $a< b$. I don't think definite integration carries a meaning when done backwards.

Comment: Isn't there the thing about integration when performed backward being negative; the limits reversing? I asked this because every other property I've seen defines the position of a and b to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @IshraaqParvez Still, the author *has* to mention that $a\le b$. Harry Holmes, may I see the source, where the author did *not* postulate this condition?

Comment: [Here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/ProofIntProp.aspx), in one of my math textbooks, in the notes we got sent to us...

Comment: @HarryHolmes I looked at his [definition](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/DefnofDefiniteIntegral.aspx) of the real integral. As ususal he says that $x\in[a,b]$, where $[a,b]:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid a\le x\le b\}$, so he mentioned it. No mistake here, but I agree with you he should have made it clearer.

Comment: Okay, just needed to know that the condition is correct. Guess he just defined the interval there to not have to repeat himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it must be said that $a\le b$, otherwise the inequality is clearly false. (For some strange reason someone downvoted your question, but it is a good question to clarify ideas).

To add something, the property cited follows from the definition of the integral of Riemann. If we use the integral of Lebesgue then the notation used doesn't lead to any confusion about $a\le b$ because we just write $\int_{[c,d]}f $ instead of $\int_c^d f$. For the integral of Lebesgue the property holds as well.